# How to count customers who visited a destination also visited another destination?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: Screen1]We have to show the count of customers who visited india also have visited to srilanka. As the count of Customer in a particular Destination(India) (ex cust.-A & cust-B, count=2) and  Destination (Srilanka)(ex cust-A, count=1).
I have columns as Cust ID and Destination.

Expected Result:
                  India   ,    Srilanka

Cross visits :-         2      ,      1

In the below image link there is overall count of customers under each destination, when we click on particular destination(City Walk) in slicer the cards under should show the count values of customers who have visited particularly clicked destination as well as the customers who are in other destinations also.

Based on the destination selection, this will showcase the customers' (unique) who have visited/connected to other destinations within the defined period of time, e.g. Customers who visited "City Walk" have also visited "Bluewaters" and "La Mer", etc.

Thank You for your information. But we have show to this data in each individual card and should be changed according to clicking on the Destinations in the slicer. I have placed the image link in the question as Screen1, please look into it.

[Report Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIcb1.png)

Comment: I'm speculating this is a scenario for [Basket Analysis](https://www.daxpatterns.com/basket-analysis/) pattern, but can you provide more illustration of your data and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply "Basket Analysis" pattern.

Basket analysis is a general term referring to "Customers who bought A also bought B". Marco Russo explains how to solve this pattern of problem in [DAX Patterns](https://www.daxpatterns.com/basket-analysis/). This fits in your scenario by just rewording "Customers who bought A also bought B" to "Customers who visited A also visited B".

Here is step by step how to.

For illustration, I would like to use a dummy visit data, which looks like below. In this data, there are 4 visitors and 3 destinations.

[image: visit data]

When I load this data into the model, I also created Visitors and Destinations tables using Power Query, which holds unique visitors and destinations respectively.

In the Modeling tab, I created a calculated table named "Second Destinations", which is just a clone of Destinations defined as DAX formula `Second Destinations = Destinations`.

Then I made relationships between tables. This is basically as star schema with a fact table Visits and 3 dimension tables. Note the relationship between Second Destinations and Visits is in dotted line. It is necessary to be inactive.

[image: model diagram]

Now define a measure to count how many visitors visited the first destination also visited the second destination. A minimal formula would be like this.

```
Cross Visits = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Visits[VisitorID]),
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(Visits, Visitors[VisitorID]),
        ALL(Destinations),
        USERELATIONSHIP('Second Destinations'[Destination], Visits[Destination])
    )
)
```

Using Destination and Second Destination, we were able to get the expected output.

[image: output]

Comment: Thank You for your information. But we have show to this data in each individual card and should be changed according to clicking on the Destinations in the slicer. I have placed the image link in the question as Screen1, please look into it. And i' have placed the .pbix file in the question.

Comment: What I show is a modeling pattern which works regardless of the type of visualization. Indeed this should work for the card by filtering the card with Second Destination and slicer with Destination.